# What if a self signed CA expired but the certificates signed by it still not?

Tags: ssl, self-signed

Say i created a self signed root certificate that will expire in 1 year. Then i use it to sign a server certificate that will expire in 10 years. What happend in the 2nd year and later years? Will the server certificate still valid if i use the expired root certificate for validation?

Comment: No, it will no longer be valid.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120469/can-a-ssl-certificate-have-longer-validity-period-than-its-parent-in-x-509-chain